# PHP - change timezone display for whole site

Tags: php, datetime

I have a website which displays dates from database using `date()` function. Now I have to add support for various timezones. Time needs to be changed only for display purposes in the front end. I used `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London')`, but it did not affect the date output - it stays the same as in the database. Function `date_default_timezone_get()` shows that the timezone is set successfully, but the date output stays the same. How can I change the global output of date? Can it be done without editing all the `date()` functions in the site?

Full example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo date_default_timezone_get(); //shows Europe/London
$date_from_db = '2014-02-02 12:34:05'; //this is generally taken from database
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date_from_db));
```

Outputs the same as before.

Comment: What timezone was used to store the dates?

Comment: So you can't use `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone`?

Comment: Server default timezone - GMT +1 if I remember correctly.

Comment: What if you call `strtotime()` before you set the default timezone?

Comment: By setting it before setting the date, aren't you telling it that the input is in that timezone?

Answer (score 1):

If your dates are stored in GMT, you can let `strtotime()` know by appending the timezone:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date_from_db GMT"));
```

*Of course, setting `Europe/London` as the timezone, the results are likely the same.*

Or, in your case:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$date_from_db +0100"));
// 2014-02-02 11:34:05
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DateTime class - see examples on this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```